# Canvas wrapped in pane (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx

We are trying to make frogger like game in JavaFX. We have classes such as player,car and log. The problem is that we are drawing our player directly on the canvas using gc.drawImage(), and the car/log objects are added to pane (we are using pathtransition to animate the logs). This is causing the player to end up underneath the log object. Is there anyway to get the player to end up on top the log?  When the player intersects with the log, we want it to be placed on top of the log and follow it.

Comment: `canvas.toFront()`

Comment: Is it possible to only place the player in front?

Comment: create another Canvas for the player only and put it in front.

Comment: Why aren't you drawing the player to the pane as well? Maybe even use a Stackpane.